# Warning SecTrustEvaluate [leaf AnchorTrusted] in device logs

Tags: ios, security

I have below code for retrieving the private key

```
-(SecKeyRef)getKey:(NSData *)pkcs12Data
{ 
   SecKeyRef privateKeyRef = nil;

    if(pkcs12Data ==nil || pkcs12Data.length==0)
    {
       return privateKeyRef;
    }

NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"", kSecImportExportPassphrase, nil];
CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);

// this line gives the warning <Error>: Nov xxxxxxx  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf AnchorTrusted]
OSStatus returnCode = SecPKCS12Import(
                                      (__bridge CFDataRef) pkcs12Data,
                                      (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) options,
                                      & items
                                      );
if(errSecSuccess == returnCode)
{
    NSDictionary *item = (NSDictionary*) CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items, 0);
    SecIdentityRef  identity = (__bridge SecIdentityRef) [item objectForKey:(__bridge NSString *) kSecImportItemIdentity];
    SecIdentityCopyPrivateKey(identity, &privateKeyRef);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"failed “);
}
return privateKeyRef;
}
```

where pkcs12Data is data of .pfx file.
Although everything is working fine but I am getting the warning in SecTrustEvaluate [leaf AnchorTrusted] in device logs. I don’t have any reason for this. Please let me know how to get rid of this warning.